# How to load a task using loadNpmTask in gruntfile if module is in different directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gruntfile

Trying to load  module: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');` from an external directory.

Get an error: **task .... does not exist. Have you loaded it?**

Directory structure:

```
client/
  node_modules
  gruntfile
dev_server/
  node_modules/
    grunt-express-server
```

So my question is: **how do you run a grunt-task using a node-module which is stored in a external directory?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use [grunt.task.loadtasks](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadtasks) pointing it to the task directory which you want to load the tasks.

In your case:

```
grunt.loadTasks('../dev_server/node_modules/grunt-express-server/tasks');
```

If you check grunt's master on github, at line 325 of [task.js](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/task.js) it requires the taskfile (.../tasks/express.js) located in the filepath you passed as parameter.

```
// Load taskfile.
fn = require(path.resolve(filepath))
```

**Edit**

If you're wondering if you can relocate the grunt's path to `node_modules`, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738177/grunt-possible-to-relocate-node-modules-for-plugins)

Comment: when it not trigger the task maybe wanna take a [look](https://gist.github.com/brutalcrozt/83b0296a536cb923073b)