# Is there a way to tell grunt where the node_modules is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am coding a lot of individual plugins for my websites and I am using `grunt` to manage the final distribution of them.
I'm used to write `grunt.loadNpmTasks` to import a specific plugin from the `node_modules` directory right into my `Gruntfile` performing the tasks.

However, in order to do that, i always `npm install <package> --save-dev` to make the plugin available in the specific plugin i am coding. But as they are dozens of plugins i am maintaining now, i found out the `node_modules` directories are growing quite bigger, and my backup gets more and more slowly as the node_modules directories are full of files.

Is there a way to centralize the plugins ? so I can reunite all the node_modules directories in one ? and tell `grunt` where this central repository stands as to load a particular plugin ?

**edit**: I tried to install `grunt-contrib-less` globally (-g) for the test, but it still persist to say `Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-less" not found. Is it installed?`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16738177/grunt-possible-to-relocate-node-modules-for-plugins

Comment: in other words, no. I also personally wished it was possible, though.

Comment: Could you have a node_modules folder in one place, and then symlink it into the rest? never tried.

Comment: @KevinB I am using wind*ws right now though

Comment: windows has the same functionality, just under a different name. If only i could remember what it's called...

Comment: @KevinB not wrong, but i don't really like that because it sounds more like a trick. I wished this functionality was directly available as a js directive.. but still thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this. but it's worth trying. Instead of using `grunt.loadNpmTasks` try using `load-grunt-tasks`.

You should use the `config` option which allows you to specify the path of your `pacakge.json`.

```
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {config: '../package'});
```

Comment: it says, **cannot find the 'load-grunt-tasks' module**

Comment: `npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks`. 
You will ended up with two `package.json` files. The first one is your original `package.json` file which will host your local `grunt` and `load-grunt-tasks` (and allows you to run grunt), the second one is the one that will include all the other modules an is being referenced in your load-grunt-tasks `config` option.